# zip archive from a directory tree but only include files with extensions xx1,xx2,...?

Tags: unix, macos

What's a combination of commands on MacOS that'll start at the root of some directory tree and create a zip file archive of it, preserving directory structure, but only including files with extensions "ext1" and "ext2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
cd DIRECTORY/..
find DIRECTORY -type f '(' -name '*.ext1' -or -name '*.ext2' ')' | xargs zip OUTPUT
```

(First chdir to the parent of the desired directory so that the paths in the ZIP file will include that directory but no parents in its path names).